# migration wordpress to local machine does not work with all broken URLs except frontpage

Tags: migration, xampp

I installed XAMPP on my Win 10 PC and migrated my wordpress website onto my PC. After migration, only the frontpage works. The other URLs would get a "Not Found". The frontpage is only partially working but I see a page nevertheless.

I have change required data in wp_options. In wp_posts, I changed the URL in column guid. I have also tinkered with apache configurations but with no success. Setting debug to true in wp-config.php does not reveal anything unusual. May I know if you have any suggestions on what else I should tweak?

wp-admin works only if I do localhost/bs/wp-admin instead of localhost/wp-admin . I tried resaving the permalink but the links remain broken.

Thanks buttered_toast. The htaccess made the files visible. Is there another location where I need to change, I spot :

```
 
include(./php/depth2.php) file not found"
```

I use PHP Code Snippet (Otherwise known as XYZ PHP) plugin. I have marked up your answers. The themes seems to be defaulting to standard Avada themes.

Comment: About `wp-admin`, yes, if your wordpress is located in htdocs/bs/, your url will always be with the prefix localhost/bs, so you need to change every old url in the DB to http://localhost/bs. Other than that I can't help, I can't know what plugins couse problems, i suggest deactivating plugins until your site runs as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When migrating a live site to local you need to do a couple of thing.

1. update the site url, you can do this in wp_options column (phpmyadmin) or in wp-config.php
2. You need to find and replace all instances of the old url, you can use [better search replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/), its a great plugin for exactly that
3. update the .htaccess to indicate the correct path of your wordpress

That should be enough for most cases

> EDIT

[image]

Lets say that your wordpress site is located in htdocs/mysite

The RewriteBase and RewriteRule should be like this

```
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I did all that you have mentioned but still not working. 1. Made the change in wp_options. 2. I used VIM to search and replace. 3. I don't see any phrase relating to the path. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Could you include the location (folder name) of your wordpress site in xampp and the code insde the .htaccess

Comment: I read that it may not be safe to expose my .htaccess . The path to my root is C:\xampp\htdocs\kr . If there is specific block of code in htaccess that you want to know, please tell.

Comment: I have added an example for .htaccess, you need to change it accordingly depending on your folders structure